# Angular ControlValueAccessor fire old value in (change) event

Tags: angular, angular6, controlvalueaccessor

I am using Angular v6.0.0 and my component is implements ControlValueAccessor;

In change event I see it alway old value, but when bind the value of ngModel it is new value.
I have made a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-switch-demo);

```
 @HostListener('click')
  onToggle() {
    if (this.disabled) {
      return;
    }
    this.checked = !this.checked;
    this.change.emit(this.checked);
    this.changed(this.checked);
    this.touched(this.checked);
  }

  // Implement control value accessor

  changed = (_: any) => {};

  touched = (_: any) => {};

  public writeValue(obj: any) {
    if (obj !== this.checked) {
      this.checked = !!obj;
    }
  }

  public registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.changed = fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.touched = fn;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use **EventEmmiter** then you have to pass $event in **output** event because **$event** hold the emitted value

here's is an example

```
<app-switch size="small" name="skip_notification" (change)="changed($event)" [(ngModel)]="value"></app-switch>
```

and in `.ts`

```
 changed(event) {
    this.value1 = event;
  }
```

here is updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggle-switch-demo-t5mztd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)